# BIRT - creating a temporary table

Tags: postgresql, birt

I am building a BIRT report based on a dynamic table. I have a function that needs to return a table with variable number of columns of different types, so we have decided that this function will create a temporary table and just return its name.
So in the BIRT beforeFactory I am running the query that calls this function and then I am trying to read from the table of returned name and create a report table dynamically based on the number of columns and types. Two questions:
1. Is there a better way to return a table with variable number of columns? (this cannot be all the possible columns that I later filter as that would exceed maximum number of allowed columns)? 
2. How to make Birt to see my temporary table? Here is the code, that I run in beforeFactory. Apparenty the table does not exists when calling second query.

```
importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn);

//Get Data Source
var dataSource = 
reportContext.getDesignHandle().getDesign().findDataSource("mydb");

//Create Data Set for data table name
var elementFactory = 
reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getElementFactory();
var dataSet = elementFactory.newOdaDataSet("tableName", 
"org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JdbcSelectDataSet");
dataSet.setDataSource(dataSource.getName());
dataSet.setQueryText("select table_name from my_export_function('str1', 
'str2');");

reportContext.getDesignHandle().getDataSets( ).add(dataSet);

//Create Data Session
var myconfig = 
reportContext.getReportRunnable().getReportEngine().getConfig();
var des = DataRequestSession.newSession(myconfig, new DataSessionContext(3));
var dset = reportContext.getDesignHandle().findDataSet("tableName");

des.defineDataSource(des.getModelAdaptor()
.adaptDataSource(reportContext.getDesig nHandle()
.findDataSource("mydb")));

des.defineDataSet(des.getModelAdaptor()
.adaptDataSet(reportContext.getDesignHandle()
.findDataSet("tableName")));

//Query Definition
queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition();
queryDefinition.setDataSetName(dataSet.getName());
queryDefinition.setAutoBinding(true);

var pq = des.prepare(queryDefinition);
var qr = pq.execute(null);
var ri = qr.getResultIterator(); 
var tableName = "";
while (ri.next()) { 
 tableName = ri.getString("table_name");
}

var dataSet2 = elementFactory.newOdaDataSet("reportData", 
"org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JdbcSelectDataSet");
dataSet2.setDataSource(dataSource.getName());
dataSet2.setQueryText("select * from " + tableName + ";");
System.out.println("TTTT: " + dataSet2.getQueryText());
reportContext.getDesignHandle().getDataSets( ).add(dataSet2);


//Query Definition
queryDefinition2 = new QueryDefinition();
queryDefinition2.setDataSetName(dataSet2.getName());
queryDefinition2.setAutoBinding(true);

var pq2 = des.prepare(queryDefinition2);
var qr2 = pq2.execute(null);
var ri2 = qr2.getResultIterator( ); 
var cc = ri2.getResultMetaData().getColumnCount();
System.out.println("col_01_name: " + 
  ri2.getResultMetaData().getColumnLabel(1));
System.out.println("Count: " + cc);

while (ri2.next()) { 
    System.out.println("Table:  "+ ri2);
    System.out.println("col_01: "+ ri2.getValue("col_01"));
}

ri.close();
qr.close();
ri2.close();
qr2.close();
des.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the code work. Following lines solved the problem with second query:

```
var des2 = DataRequestSession.newSession(myconfig, new DataSessionContext(3));
des2.defineDataSource(des2.getModelAdaptor()
.adaptDataSource(reportContext.getDesig nHandle()
.findDataSource("mydb")));

des2.defineDataSet(des2.getModelAdaptor()
.adaptDataSet(reportContext.getDesignHandle()
.findDataSet("tableName")));
```

and then:

```
var pq2 = des2.prepare(queryDefinition2);
```

Also we have changed the function to return the query instead of creating a temporary table.